# How do I center this form-button block?

Tags: html, css

I want this form band button to line up horizontally and to sit as a whole in the horizontal center of the page.

How do I set my css?

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post">
         <fieldset>
          <label>Email: <label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder='email address' />
          <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class= "button" />
          </fieldset>
          </form>
```

Comment: You didn't close your LABEL correctly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plenty of ways to tackle this. Here is one solution. Though, I do recommend not using inline styles, but here is your form with the CSS.

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 350px;">
  <fieldset>
    <label>Email: <label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder='email address' />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class= "button" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks!. How do I hide the borders around the form body?

Comment: The `border` comes from the `fieldset`. Use `<fieldset style="border: 0">`, but remember that inline styles are not good.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap your inputs in a div and set the div to display:inline in your css.  In your css also target your form and set that to margin:auto

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
<div style="width: 300px; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <form action="signup.php" method="post">
         <fieldset>
          <label>Email: <label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder='email address' />
          <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class= "button" />
          </fieldset>
      </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Dmitriy Better: `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Not better! The same :) BUT My Way it would be more clear for him, if he does not have hands on experience with stuff like that.

Comment: @Dmitriy How is 14 characters of code not better than 37 characters of code? Smaller code = better.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: 23 saved characters! so much! your page will load so much faster than mine! honestly outstanding :))

Comment: @Dmitriy You do understand that this has nothing to do with performance, right?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you understand that. For me its matter of preference, if it is not matter of performance.

Comment: @Dmitriy What do you mean? You prefer to have a larger code size?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I think you are flooding already. Yes, for explanation to the newbie I prefer longer code size.

Comment: @Dmitriy I'm not familiar with the term "flooding" in this context. What does it mean?